# Magento Use Flat Catalog Category in Admin greyed out and can't changed value

Tags: magento

We have **Magento Community version 1.9.0.1**. We activated Use Flat Catalog Category from `admin`>`system`>`configuration`>`frontend`. when we activated and tried to reindex it gave us an error message of missing `catalog_category_flat_store_1`. Now Use Flat Catalog Category in admin is greyed out and can't change it. Then we created that manually but after that we get this error message:

```
Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`catalog_category_flat_store_1`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_CTGR_FLAT_STORE_1_ENTT_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`) )' in /www/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /www/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /www/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /www/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /www/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(1998): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#6 /www/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(1971): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->insertArray('catalog_categor...', Array, Array)
#7 /www/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php(539): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->insertMultiple('catalog_categor...', Array)
#8 /www/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php(1482): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->rebuild()
#9 /www/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Indexer/Flat.php(260): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->reindexAll()
#10 /www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#11 /www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#12 /www/shell/indexer.php(166): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#13 /www/shell/indexer.php(212): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
```

Not able to figure it out what exactly is the problem and where to start. Log doesn't say anything. We disable flat product and truncated and reindexed but still Use Flat Catalog Category dropdown is disable and not able to change value. So my only option is to reindex Use Flat Catalog Category until then it won't show Menu in our website..

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a programming-related question?

Answer (score 0):

Probably catalog_category_flat_store_1 is corrupted. I would rename that table to catalog_category_flat_store_1_OLD (for example) and then from ssh I would try to reindex again from folder /shell with `php -f indexer.php -- -reindex catalog_category_flat`. That have to  regenerate the  table again with your categories.

Comment: Now it give this error..Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'france_mag2.catalog_category_flat_store_1' (errno: 121)' in /home/francedv/www/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234

Comment: Looks something related with the whole database or an index misconfiguration. I suggest you to try a search in Google with the words 'magento Can't create table flat ' because It can be anything (permissions,innodb,indexes...)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by replacing

```
$app = Mage::app(0);
```

with

```
Mage::app("admin");
```

in my import script.